# Efficient ip lookup

Tags: python, networking, ip, lookup

I have a file, f1 that contains a list of 42,000,000 ip addresses.
I have another file, f2 that contains a dictionary of ipranges and their associated owner like :

```
Regional Physicians Neuroscience,[('66.110.238.100', '66.110.238.100')]
Coast Institute of Technology,[('41.89.132.0', '41.89.132.255')]
House Of Flowers,[('69.15.170.220', '69.15.170.223'), ('108.178.223.20', '108.178.223.23')]
```

Now I am wondering what the most efficient way for each ip in f1 to find its associated range and owner. For example like :

```
ip1, House Of Flowers , ('69.15.170.220', '69.15.170.223')
```

Can anybody help me in this regards??

Answer (score 2):

We assume that the ip ranges cannot overlap; so if you sort them in ascending order by base address, you can use `bisect.bisect_left` to index into the array. Then if `array[index].first_address <= search_address <= .last_address` you have found a match, otherwise no match exists.

Alternatively, dump it all into a database, index on first_address and last_address, and let the database worry about searching efficiently. See [the sqlite documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sqlite3.html).

Answer (score 1):

### Be non-pythonic for once...

If the total number of possible owners is small (less than 255) but the number of ranges is large (hundreds) you could **convert each IP into the four-byte integer** that it represents and then **use it to index into a huge array of bytes**.

The byte value found is the owner number, 255 means nobody.

The array needed will be 4 GB max and much smaller if you first test for the min-max range that your owners actually require.